# node express- error while trying to listen on port 80

Tags: node.js, windows, express

I'm trying to run a node application on a windows machine.

This application uses 'express' that listens to port 80. when running it I get the following error:

```
Error: bind EACCES 127.0.0.1:80
```

I know that on Linux I can run it with 'sudo', or give privilege to a user and port, but I don't know how to do it on windows

running as admin didn't work

[image]

Comment: try running `cmd` with admin privileges?

Comment: I would avoid running node as admin just to access the port, it's probably better to run node on a high port (eg 3000) and add a port ridirect using a netsh interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** As a general rule if you don't have admin access you should select port above `1024`.

But for windows, You can always open `cmd` as administrator and run `node` in it.

*For example:* right click on the left corner(or ctrl+x) and select `Run cmd as administrator`

Now, sometimes in Win8+ I believe there is service called `World Wide Web Publishing Service` which uses **Port 80**. So if you need to close that run `services.msc` and find that service and (you can ) stop it.

Comment: thanks a lot. this service: World Wide Web Publishing Service took the port. this is strange because I was expecting a "port already in use"  error, so I didn't suspect the IIS.

Comment: I did. it didn't allow me to do it before X minutes from the question time :)